# Classification of data points in multivariate time series based on multiple multivariate time series

Tags: python, machine-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I would like to ask whether the use of `RNN`s is applicable for a specific problem.

I have multiple multivariate time series and each data point is labeled with numbers from 1 to 16.
A strict increasing order is applied to my labels (successive data points in my time series can only have labels larger or equal to the previous data points).
These time series define my training set.

I would like to classify a new unlabeled multivariate time series by considering the sequence in the label changes at my training set. A typical `ANN` is not applicable since it does not considers all previous occurrences.

Since this is not a typical forecasting problem, are `RNN`s applicable?